# Modal Window hidden behind container

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, z-index

I have a container div that with lots of items(divs) inside of it. When i hover this items, a little modal is showing. The problem is that this modal is should be on top of the container but this is not the case, even though it has a higher z-index.

The modal class is: csgo-item--title

My Html:

```
<div class="container-trade panel panel-default">

    <div class="csgo-item csgo-item--rare"">

         <div class="csgo-item--title">
               <!--Random Stuff Here -->
           </div>
     </div>

 </div>
```

My Css:

```
.container-trade{
    background-color: rgba(255, 240, 240, 0.5) !important;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
}

.csgo-item{
    min-height: 80px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.csgo-item--title{
width: 370px !important;
    left: -132px !important;
    top: 95px !important;
    min-height: 150px !important;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: fit-content;
    background: rgb(66, 60, 70);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #2d2d2d;
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:999;
}
```

This is what is happening: https://gyazo.com/fa9948d2d6f7ddac7bce8e2743d56053

I have tried changing the position and the z-index on the different elements, but it doesn't work. What can i do?

Comment: What if you don't nest the div within a div within a div? The div in the div has no where to go, it'll still be eclipsed because its under the other div on the structural (html) level.

Comment: @I.R.R. I need that div. I just removed all the code that it had inside because there was no point of showing it here.Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: What I meant was you can try restructuring your divs to be parallel instead of nested, then play with the css again.